# Why does pyuff only provide a string of size 80 when it should be longer?

Tags: python, string, size, data-import

I am using pyuff to open a .unv file. The titles of the individual experiments that are saved in the file can be quite long as they describe the testing situation and procedure that was used.

When loading the file into python with pyuff the title should be saved in "id 4" as:

Record    4 of section "newTests_3007_SA", run "LASER_L_aussen_links_IMPACT_R1_STRONGER

but instead it stops reading after the string has reached the size 80.
Resulting in

Record    4 of section "newTests_3007_SA", run "LASER_L_aussen_links_IMPACT_R1_S

I narrowed the problem down to this section of the code:

```
uff_file = pyuff.UFF(path)
uniFile_data = uff_file.read_sets()
```

But I could not find any information on how to increase the maximum string size.

As my .unv-file is very large i would like to avoid changing the individual title names manually.